# Is it possible to only save images in Android app private directory, rather the internal or any external storage of device?

Tags: android, android-storage

I do not want to store my Android app images on internal or external device storage so that it will become visible to the gallery.

Right now, I am saving my app images on the external device storage. But I want to save the images into the application private directory. How can I achieve this?

Here is my **activity** code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                    // Get the path from the Uri

                    String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                    File file = new File(path);
                    Bitmap bmp = CommonMethod.compressImage(file, getContext());
                    Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult --: " + String.format("Size : %s", getReadableFileSize(file.length())));

                    mCustomerImage = CommonMethod.bitmapToByteArray(bmp);
                    imageTemplateStr = Base64.encodeToString(mCustomerImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Log.e(TAG, "image: " + imageTemplateStr);
                    //CommonMethod.SaveImage(bmp);
                    imageCustomer.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    CommonMethod.SaveImage(bmp);
                }

            } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                    // Get the path from the Uri

                    String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                    File file = new File(path);
                    Bitmap bmp = CommonMethod.compressImage(file, getContext());
                    Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult --: " + String.format("Size : %s", getReadableFileSize(file.length())));

                    mCustomerImage = CommonMethod.bitmapToByteArray(bmp);
                    imageTemplateStr = Base64.encodeToString(mCustomerImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    //CommonMethod.SaveImage(bmp);
                    Log.e(TAG, "image: " + imageTemplateStr);

                    imageCustomer.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    CommonMethod.SaveImage(bmp);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**SaveImage Method**

```
 public static void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/.safco_private_pics");
    if (!myDir.exists()) {
        myDir.mkdirs();
    }
    File newFile = new File(root,".nomedia");
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newFile);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ())
        file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**getPathFromUri Method**

```
public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource) ? [graphic guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/)

Comment: then where do you want to save it ? .. do u mean on web ?

Comment: Read [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800491/how-to-hide-images-from-android-gallery) . And for sake of searching do not add IDE tag with question unless question is not about IDE i.e `android-studio`.

Comment: `NOT on internal not on external device storage` Then you should save your images on Cloud storage.

Comment: I am using SQLite database @ADM

Comment: yes on server or SQLite database . or is there any other solution by which images can be deleted after use . ? @bhardwaj

Comment: @RashidKalhoro You have 3 options. Database ,Local Storage or Cloud . You can save images in Apps cache directory that is internal storage. Read https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.

Comment: As it has been written in comments, you can save them 
1) in directory and make it invisible to galleries
2) server (cloud), internet required
3) DB, but it is not recommended (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931301/app-crash-when-selecting-more-than-10-images)

I would store as File in app private directory and hide it from galleries

Comment: yes i am storing it privately and trying to hide from gallery but my client is bonehead . @JemshitIskenderov i created a file on external storage hide and save image in it but still images are visible in my gallery?

Comment: Hiding is easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800491/how-to-hide-images-from-android-gallery

And store image in App Private directory, so user does not see it easily or other apps can't delete it. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage

Comment: i tried both ways .nomedia and .hiddenfolder but still not working @JemshitIskenderov please look at my code , what is wrong?

.nomedia file is not created , please check why

Comment: If you put all images in folderA and folderA has .nomedia file, all images in that folder must be invisible to gallery app. Refresh the gallery, maybe it will hide then (it should hide).

Comment: yes i add .nomdeia file manually it worked but when i took new image that image is visible again @JemshitIskenderov

Comment: You sure new image is in same directory as .nomedia ? Also did you store them to app private directory? If so i would blame gallery app.

Comment: yes it is same directory but the problem is image is also stored in my DCIM/Camera folder , how to get rid of that ? @JemshitIskenderov then that image is visible in gallery

Comment: Dont store it in DCIM/Camera folder then.

Comment: haha i don't want but idk how is it storing inside DCIM , can u tell from my code @JemshitIskenderov

Comment: Solved my Problem , Thanks Every one .

Comment: @ADM i got banned from asking questions so please give upvote on my questions i don't see how are my question aree not relevant ?

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov i got banned from asking questions so please give upvote on my questions i don't see how are my question aree not relevant ? –

Comment: @bhardwaj i got banned from asking questions so please give upvote on my questions i don't see how are my question aree not relevant ? –