# App crash when selecting more than 10 images

Tags: java, android

I am coding an  android app using android studio - java , I am facing a problem when picking more than 10 images from gallery and inserting them into `Sqlitedatabase` table , when inserting the 10th image it takes much longer time than the last 9 images , and when selecting all the images (10) from the table the app crashes with errors

> E/SQLiteCursor: onMove() return false. RequiredPos: 9 WindowStartPos: 9 WindowRowCount: 0(original count of query: 10)
>   Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 10

Code

> Picking and inserting images code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode== 1  && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
            if (clipData == null)
                return;
            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri());
                byte[] myImg = getBitmapAsByteArray(bitmap);
                DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
                SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put("myImage",myImg);
                db.insert("myTable",null,contentValues);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> getBitmapAsByteArray()

```
 private static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

> Selecting images from database

```
 public void showImages(View view) {
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from myTable",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+cursor.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            bitmaps.add(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(cursor.getBlob(0), 0, cursor.getBlob(0).length));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this,bitmaps);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    cursor.close();
}
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Share your tried Code Please

Comment: your cursor is not having that much of entries that you are trying to access.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the code, but i **would not store image directly** in Database. Image can be really huge, it might take some time to write and read multiple images.

Instead, like what backend developers do, i would store image as File on Filesystem ([app private directory](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage)). They will be deleted when app is deleted. Save the images as Files and store their path or name into DB. So whenever you need image, just do:

1. `List<String> getImageNamesFromDb()`
2. `List<File> getImageFiles(List<String>)`
3. `processYourImageFiles(List<File>)`

Comment: hey i used this way to save images but it slowed down my app , i think it keeps reading the pictures from the file all the time , when i had them in the database and call "select" it was loading all the photos and show them , it was much faster , any suggestions ?

Comment: @RaedGhazal LruCache: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap

Comment: hey can we talk in any chat app for a faster communication , cuz i am not really getting how to cache images from internal storage , tried alot of ways and non worked

Answer (score 0):

It is an index out of bound exception.
Your loop is going in negative , you are accessing a row at index -1 which does not exist.
Try errors in your loop.
Please give your code of java file.
It might help more for finding more errors.